# Hover on an Object to transform another

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have two circles (divs) in HTML. How do I click on one circle to transform the other circle (say change its opacity:0.5;) using transition in CSS3

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

use "+" selector

```
<div>
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
</div>
```

this css makes what you want to do

```
.circle2{
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.circle1:hover + .circle2{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

use jQuery if you want to change opacity when you click circle1

Comment: The correct CSS rule is .circle2{
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.circle1:hover + .circle2{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you'd like to use jQuery, here is what you could do:

```
  //select circle1 and do something when it's clicked
  $('.circle1').click(function() {

    //when circle1 clicked, do something to circle2
  $('.circle2').css('opacity', '.5');

 });
```